# show hidden div on list items

Tags: javascript, jquery

html:

I have a ul list with each li counstructed like this:

```
   <li class="A">list-item
     <div>1</div>
     <div class="B">2
        <div class="C">3</div>
     </div>

   </li>
```

where div C has css property display:none;
I wrote this js:

```
   $(".A").hover(function () {
   $(".C").toggle();
   });
```

that shows hidden divs on li hover, but I would like js working only on active li item. 
So when i hover li item it shows only that list item hidden div.

any suggestions? I am new with js, so any help would be appreciated, thnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) to narrow the lookup to the desired element's children.

```
$(".A").hover(function () {
   $(".C", this).toggle();
});
```

Comment: @smerny it is a very negligible difference, else this method would not be provided by `jQuery`

Comment: The reason there's negligible difference is because jQuery uses the `find()` method, internally, to apply selector context.

Comment: @DavidThomas that is the whole point, it is a convenient method provided by jQuery, so until you are processing 1000s of records there is no reason not to use it

Comment: Except for the minor performance cost, and the deliberate obfuscation of a similarly easy-to-read method-chain. It really does make little difference, and if this is your preferred style, then no reason to change, but I (personally, ymmv, etc) prefer to explicitly use `find()`.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this, it will find class `C` within `this` (which will be the element being hovered)

```
$(".A").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".C").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [**hover()**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), the correct format of `hover` function is:

```
$(".A").hover(
  function () {
    // A function to execute when the mouse pointer enters the element.
    $(this).find(".C").show();
  },
  function () {
    // A function to execute when the mouse pointer leaves the element.
    $(this).find(".C").hide();
  }
);
```

Comment: since .C is originally hidden, using just toggle will have the same affect: http://jsfiddle.net/M3TE9/